# ESP32 Arduino ps_malloc works but not if i wrap it in a function

Tags: c++, malloc, wrapper, arduino-esp32

I often use the external ram in ESP32 for json document serialization for which i use ArduinoJson library. I wanted to wrap memory allocation into a function for reuse and readability but it is crashing my code. The crash message is all over the place but i paste it here.

**Here is how i often use ps_malloc (which works)**

```
#define CONFIG_SIZE 2000
char* configBuff = (char *) ps_malloc (CONFIG_SIZE * sizeof (char));
if( !configBuff ){
    Serial.println("Can't allocate buffer for configuration data");
    return;
}
```

Now i want to do the same but using a function call.

Here is the function i tought would work. (it is inside a class but ignore that part)

```
/*
*   Allocates a character array in PS ram with the given size.
*   Mainly used for JsonDocument allocation and serialization.
*   Returns true if the allocation has succeded, false otherwise.
*/
boolean Sys::alloc(char* ptr,size_t size){
    ptr = (char *) ps_malloc (size * sizeof (char));
    if( !ptr || ptr == NULL ){ return false; }
    return true;
}
```

And i would use it like this:

```
#define CONFIG_SIZE 2000
char* configBuff;
if( !sys.alloc(configBuff ,CONFIG_SIZE ){
    Serial.println("Can't allocate buffer for configuration data");
    return;
}
```

My code crashes horribly if i use the wrapper function.

Here is the crash log which is mostly ArduinoJson complaining because of the serialization.
My code goes past this function call, so it is allocated the space required, but after that i call `SerializeJson()` and this happens.
Serialization looks like this: `serializeJson(JSONDOC,configBuff,CONFIG_SIZE)`

Using latest ArduinoJson which can be found here: https://arduinojson.org

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4019da9a  PS      : 0x00060b30  A0      : 0x800dbe2c  A1      : 0x3ffd20d0  
A2      : 0x3ffd2114  A3      : 0x0000005b  A4      : 0x00001388  A5      : 0x3ffc50f0
A6      : 0x3ffc50f0  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00000001  A9      : 0x00000000
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x00000404  A12     : 0x00001400  A13     : 0x00000000
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x3ffca95c  SAR     : 0x00000001  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008b0a4  LEND    : 0x4008b0af  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000


Backtrace:0x4019da97:0x3ffd20d00x400dbe29:0x3ffd20f0 0x400dbf12:0x3ffd2110 0x400dc082:0x3ffd2140 0x400e5aee:0x3ffd21c0 0x400e3491:0x3ffd2210 0x400e35ae:0x3ffd2260 0x400e37a1:0x3ffd22b0 0x40182f4e:0x3ffd22d0 0x40182fc9:0x3ffd2300 0x401838ca:0x3ffd2320 

  #0  0x4019da97:0x3ffd20d0 in ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter::write(unsigned char) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Serialization/Writers/StaticStringWriter.hpp:18
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::CountingDecorator<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::write(unsigned char) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Serialization/CountingDecorator.hpp:17
  #1  0x400dbe29:0x3ffd20f0 in ArduinoJson6192_F1::TextFormatter<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::writeRaw(char) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Json/TextFormatter.hpp:162
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::write(char) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Json/JsonSerializer.hpp:108
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::visitArray(ArduinoJson6192_F1::CollectionData const&) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Json/JsonSerializer.hpp:23        
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::result_type ArduinoJson6192_F1::VariantData::accept<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>&) const at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantData.hpp:47
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::result_type ArduinoJson6192_F1::VariantData::accept<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>&) const at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantData.hpp:41
  #2  0x400dbf12:0x3ffd2110 in ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::result_type ArduinoJson6192_F1::variantAccept<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::VariantData const*, ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>&) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantFunctions.hpp:17
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::result_type ArduinoJson6192_F1::VariantConstRef::accept<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>&) const at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Variant/VariantRef.hpp:245
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::result_type ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonDocument::accept<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>&) const at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Document/JsonDocument.hpp:21
      (inlined by) unsigned int ArduinoJson6192_F1::doSerialize<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer, ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator>, ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>(ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator> const&, ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Serialization/serialize.hpp:15  
      (inlined by) ArduinoJson6192_F1::enable_if<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer<ArduinoJson6192_F1::StaticStringWriter>::producesText, unsigned int>::type ArduinoJson6192_F1::serialize<ArduinoJson6192_F1::JsonSerializer, ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator> const&, void*, unsigned int) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Serialization/serialize.hpp:36
  #3  0x400dc082:0x3ffd2140 in unsigned int ArduinoJson6192_F1::serializeJson<ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator> >(ArduinoJson6192_F1::BasicJsonDocument<SpiRamAllocator> const&, void*, unsigned int) at lib/ArduinoJson-6.x/src/ArduinoJson/Json/JsonSerializer.hpp:126
      (inlined by) operator() at src/serverSys/adminSys/adminSys.cpp:52   
      (inlined by) _M_invoke at c:\users\zekag\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:297
  #4  0x400e5aee:0x3ffd21c0 in std::function<void (AsyncWebServerRequest*)>::operator()(AsyncWebServerRequest*) const at c:\users\zekag\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:687
      (inlined by) AsyncCallbackWebHandler::handleRequest(AsyncWebServerRequest*) at lib/ESPAsyncWebServer/src/WebHandlerImpl.h:132
  #5  0x400e3491:0x3ffd2210 in AsyncWebServerRequest::_parseLine() at lib/ESPAsyncWebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:581 (discriminator 1)
  #6  0x400e35ae:0x3ffd2260 in AsyncWebServerRequest::_onData(void*, unsigned int) at lib/ESPAsyncWebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:123
  #7  0x400e37a1:0x3ffd22b0 in std::_Function_handler<void (void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int), AsyncWebServerRequest::AsyncWebServerRequest(AsyncWebServer*, AsyncClient*)::{lambda(void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int)#8}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, void*&&, AsyncClient*&&, std::_Any_data const&, unsigned int&&) at lib/ESPAsyncWebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:76
      (inlined by) _M_invoke at c:\users\zekag\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:297
  #8  0x40182f4e:0x3ffd22d0 in std::function<void (void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int)>::operator()(void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int) const at c:\users\zekag\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:687  
      (inlined by) AsyncClient::_recv(tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp-wrover-kit/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:915
  #9  0x40182fc9:0x3ffd2300 in AsyncClient::_s_recv(void*, tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp-wrover-kit/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:1191
  #10 0x401838ca:0x3ffd2320 in _async_service_task(void*) at .pio/libdeps/esp-wrover-kit/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:159
      (inlined by) _async_service_task at .pio/libdeps/esp-wrover-kit/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:194




ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
```

Comment: The pointer parameter is passed by value, so changing it inside the function is only changing that local copy. You need to either pass the address of the pointer or a reference to the pointer to assign it inside the function. Since this is C++ a reference would be preferred. `boolean Sys::alloc(char*& ptr,size_t size){ ... }`.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you. I overlooked this. It is working like this.